# Linear Transformation $\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image: Here's the question and how the answer is supposed to be]

I cannot figure this problem out. Here's what I've tried.
$$-3T(1,0,0)+ 0T(0,1,0)+5T(0,0,1)=(-3,1,0)+(4,-4,4)+(3,-1,-2)$$
I got $(4,-4,2)$ as an answer and it's incorrect. What am I doing wrong? I followed this step for step with an example the professor worked out on the board.

Comment: Zero times anything is zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, just forgetting to multiply through by those scalars:

$$-3T(1,0,0)+ 0T(0,1,0)+5T(0,0,1)=-3(-3,1,0)+0(4,-4,4)+5(3,-1,-2)=(9,-3,0)+(0,0,0)+(15,-5,-10)$$

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The vectors in the transformation are the canonic base of $\mathbb{R}^3$, then, for a theorem you can make the matriz associated to the transformation,
$$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 4 & 3 \\
1 & -4 & -1 \\
0 & 4 & -2 \end{array} \right)$$
Now, you can find $T\left( \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 0 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}\right)$
$$T\left( \begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 0 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}\right)=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & 4 & 3 \\
1 & -4 & -1 \\
0 & 4 & -2 \end{array} \right)\begin{bmatrix}-3 \\ 0 \\ 5 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}26 \\ -8 \\ -10 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

The three vectors $[-3, 1, 0]^T$, etc form the columns of the transformation matrix.  Use this matrix on the other vector.